# Best structure for this database?

Tags: database, database-design, data-structures, database-schema

**The Problem**: I want to design a website and I need a database for that, however I don't know which structure is better!

**What will happen**: Users will add some URIs to their favorites.

**Possible structures**:

*Structure one*:

```
TABLE "USERS":
=====================================================================
id | name | last_name | urls
1  | John | Smith     | [google.com,stackoverflow.com,yahoo.com,...]
=====================================================================
```

*Structure two*:

```
TABLE "USERS":
=============================================
id | name | last_name 
1  | John | Smith
2  | Joe  | Roth
==============================================

TABLE "URLS":
==============================================
id | user_id | url
1  | 1       | google.com
2  | 1       | stackoverflow.com
3  | 2       | ask.com
4  | 1       | yahoo.com
5  | 2       | being.com
==============================================
```

Which structure is best? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your second designs looks good to me.  Steer clear of the first one...

Comment: Your first "database organization" violates even the 1NF - the second is definitely better.

Comment: See [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574#3653574)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second schema (with a foreign key constraint on URLS.user_id) will be easier to manage. A `select` query will need to use a `join` and you'll be performing more `insert`s, but you won't need to perform string parsing to figure out what the urls are (which, with the first schema, you would need for every single `select` and `update`).

One of the tables in the **production** database at my current job has a schema similar to the first case, and it makes my entire department cringe and complain when they have to write code working with it. Yet the table remains, because fixing it would be a massive overhaul. (The table was created by a manager who no longer works here.) If you're creating your schema now, do it *right*, while you still can.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely create another table that save urls + user_id. Your first type is not in [Normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: Specifically, it's not in _first_ normal form.